How to avoid StackOverflow error during JSON serialization of interconnected objects in Dart?
I have a Vehicle class in Dart, where each vehicle can be connected to another vehicle using a rope or some other connection. The class has three fields:

previousCar - The vehicle that is in front.

nextCar - The vehicle that is behind.

edge - A custom Edge class representing the connection between two vehicles.


If the vehicle is the front vehicle (the one pulling), the nextCar field is null. If it is the rear vehicle, the previousCar field is null.
The Edge class contains two fields:

connectorCar: The vehicle that is connecting.

connectedCar: The vehicle that is being connected.


class Vehicle {
    final Vehicle? nextCar; 
    final Vehicle? previousCar; 
    final Edge? edge; 
    // Constructor and toJson, fromJson methods... 
    }

class Edge {
    final Vehicle connectorCar; 
    final Vehicle connectedCar; 
    // Constructor and toJson, fromJson methods... 
    }

How can I properly handle JSON serialization to avoid this circular reference issue?
When I attempt to serialize these classes to JSON using the toJson method, I encounter a StackOverflow error. This happens because of the circular reference — the Edge class has a reference to Vehicle, and the Vehicle class has a reference to Edge.

If each vehicle can only be connected either at the rear or at the front,  then would it not be easier to model the structure as a linked list say Train<Vehicle>?   Also, "If the vehicle is the front vehicle (the one pulling), the nextCar field is null. If it is the rear vehicle, the previousCar field is null." Seems like it should be the other way round.

@DanR Actually, I gave this example to keep my problem short. My problem is a little more complicated. Can you look at the mlp package on pub.dev? Actually, my problem is that I cannot store the trained model in this package as a direct object. I need to be able to serialize Json to store it. When I make the necessary additions, it loops and gives the same error because there is Edge in the Neuron class and Neuron in the Edge class, similar to the example I gave. Can your suggestion be used for this package? Cause I'm not sure. Thnx btw for your comment

YAML can handle the serialization/deserialization of self-referencing data just fine.
